# Django ConnectionAbortedError: Помогите с ошибкой

Tags: python, django, sql-server, django-orm

подскажите что за ошибка и как с ней бороться

```
----------------------------------------
[05/Feb/2021 11:46:15] "GET /admin/mainapp/order/6/change/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14103
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 62036)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\shop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Программа на вашем хост-компьютере разорвала установленное подключение
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: порт пробовал менять?

Comment: да, та же ошибка